# Need to edit in YOLO Classes

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo

In YOLO v8 I want to only the Person class after that I will want to custom train my object and I have the dataset for that. For example, if I want to train pen and charger I want to give a custom dataset for these two objects and Yolo's pre-defined class person.

At last, I want

Person - pre-trained

Pen - Custom

Charger - Custom

How to archive this? Only one or some pre-trained classes of YOLO and others are my custom objects.